# incode vertical bars in latex

Tags: symbols, unicode

i need to display the following characters:

￤ = U+FFE4

┊ = U+250A

is there a way to display them, possibly using pdflatex rather than xelatex?

Comment: For the broken vertical line, try `\brokenvert` from the `wasysym` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I just take a string of minuses and rotate/compress them to the right size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,graphicx}
\begin{document}
$\stretchrel*{\rotatebox{90}{$\!\!- -$}}{\strutbox} ={}$U+FFE4

$\stretchrel*{\rotatebox{90}{$\!\!\!\!{-} {-} {-} {-}$}}{\strutbox} ={}$U+250A
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @iobefor Thanks.   If they are too deep, you can remove some of the leading `\!` commands.